# Is it possible to cache into local org partition from a managed package?

Tags: platform-cache

Is it possible to cache into local org partition from a managed package? In other words can we do this Cache.Org.put('local.ABCPartition.XYZ', 'Test Object'); from the managed package, where in ABCPartition has been created in the org where this Managed package is installed.

Comment: Does your question relate to the comment "The cache put calls aren’t allowed in a partition that the invoking class doesn’t own." in the [Org Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Org.htm) documentation?

Comment: That is right @keith

Comment: Hey @KeithC, I don't know for sure but what I understood is that no managed package can use partitions from other managed package (namespace), but any code can use 'local' partitions.

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but my understanding is your packaged can create a parition in the local cache and use that, or you can bundle cache capacity in your package for a cost. Not sure about using existing local partitions though.